# How to validate form when the forms are inserted using ng-include

Tags: angularjs

I have 3 different form pages which are inserted using ng-include into DOM within a bootstrap modal window. What is the best way to do validation in every form and do a complete form submit(for all the 3 forms) in scenario like this?

HTML

```
<div ng-switch on="page">
    <div ng-switch-when="Games">
        <div ng-include="'Games.html'"></div>
    </div>  
    <div ng-switch-when="Music">
        <div ng-include="'Music.html'"></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="Videos">
        <div ng-include="'Videos.html'"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/D1tMRpxVzn51g18Adnp8?p=preview

Comment: Do you want to use a unique form or do you need do validation in every  form ? I mean you have to validated games than music ....

Comment: I don't think it's clear from your question what you're trying to achieve. Please consider revising.

Comment: I've modified the description now. I need to validate all the 3 forms when I click submit and if possible change the left nav text color(Games,Music..) to highlight that the form is not filled/invalid.

Comment: @eddiec i've modified the description is this understandable?

Comment: @Whisher need to validate all the 3 forms when on click of submit

Answer (score 0):

There is to find a way to validate data yet
(may be with jqueryvalidation) but can be a starting point.
I think there is no way to get the value of games.$valid 
so I've thought of

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
            app.controller("FormsCtrl", function($scope) {
               //console.log($scope);
               // $scope.items = ['Games', 'Music', 'Videos'];
                $scope.$on('someEvent',function(e,a){
                   console.log(a); 
                })
            });
            app.directive("myform", function() {
                return {
                    restrict: "A",
                    link:function(scope,element,attrs){
                        element.bind('submit',function(e){
                            var isValid = false; // TO DO :)
                            scope.$emit('someEvent', [attrs.fname,isValid]);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });



<div ng-controller="FormsCtrl"> 
      <div ng-switch on="page">
            <div ng-switch-when="Games">
                <div ng-include="'Games.html'"></div>
            </div>  
            <div ng-switch-when="Music">
                <div ng-include="'Music.html'"></div>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="Videos">
                <div ng-include="'Videos.html'"></div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>


<form name="games"  class="simple-form"  myform fname="games">
   <input type="text" ng-model="prefix.games.name" name="uName" required /><br>
</form>
```

**EDIT**
A smarter quicker way :)

```
app.controller("FormsCtrl", function($scope) {
                $scope.mySubmit = function(isValid){
                    console.log(isValid);
                }
            });


<form name="games"  class="simple-form" ng-submit="mySubmit(games.$valid)">
   <input type="text" ng-model="prefix.games.name" name="uName" required /><br>
</form>
```